# AndEngine - FPS Logging

Tags: android, andengine, frame-rate

1) What is the importance of `andEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger())`?

2) is this just for FPS logging purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Like you ask, it logs the current frames per second in the debug console.

2) Yes, it does nothing more.

The code:

http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/util/FPSLogger.java

The most interesting method is onLogFPS(). Which gets called by the overided methods that andengine calls at certain intervals.

Comment: And you should remove this line if you are not logging the FPS. It is just slowing your game.